# Disable Amazon AWS Echo to Different SSH Connections

Tags: ssh, amazon-ec2

I am on a Power Mac OSX mountain lion. I ssh into an amazon aws ec2 instance. Then I want to ssh into the same aws ec2 instance. When I do any command in one connection it is echoed in the other connection (the app I'm using is Terminal). I'm trying to run a command in one directory and see what happens in another (and occasionally tail) using the other terminal connection. Except I can't because the echoing causes both terminal connections to stay in sync... i.e. one is just a mirror of what the other is doing.

How can I disable this. I tried hitting f9 to get a menu (bottom left of the window indicates f9 should call a menu) but this does nothing.

Answer (score 1):

This is because on the instance launched [Byobu](http://byobu.co/).
You need ssh to a host and not launch Byobu at login like this:

```
ssh -t remotehost bash
```

You can also run commands in the background using the [screen](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-screen-command-howto.html) utility.

Answer (score 0):

Mac new user issue. I didn't realize that on a Mac you have to hit a fn button at the same time as the fn9 button in order to get the function button to work. Who would have thought that Apple would have such insight that you would need two buttons to make a function button labeled as a function button to work.